# GetIDsFromNames() fails when STRING name of 'NAMED Propertty' is used

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin, mapi

I am using MAPI MSG file as message source. From this message I am unable to fetch named-property using property-name. GetIDsFromNames() works when I pass ID. Please see the sample below.

```
const GUID PSETID_Common1 = {0x00062008, 0, 0, {0xC0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x46}};
MAPINAMEID  Mon1;
LPMAPINAMEID Mon1_id = &Mon1;

Mon1_id->lpguid = &PSETID_Common1;
if(useID == 0)
{   //In this case GetIDsFromNames() fails
    Mon1_id->ulKind = MNID_STRING;
    Mon1_id->Kind.lpwstrName = L"PidTagInternetAccountName";
}
else
{    //In this case GetIDsFromNames() succeeds
    Mon1_id->ulKind = MNID_ID;
    Mon1_id->Kind.lID = useID;
}

hr = obj->GetIDsFromNames(1, &Mon1_id, 0, &cols);
```

I tried using these names: dispidInetAcctName, PidTagInternetAccountName, PidNameInternetAccountName

Is GetIDsFromNames() failing because MSG lacks the information required to convert NAME->ID. I think this information is stored on EX server.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual value of hr? If the mapping does not exist yet for that particular MSG file, you must pass the MAPI_CREATE flag when calling GetIDsFromNames.

Comment: MAPI_W_ERRORS_RETURNED is the error returned by GetIDsFromNames(). As per your suggestion I started calling with MAPI_CREATE. This made GetIDsFromNames() pass. GetProps() failed when I passed the ID returned from GetIDsFromNames(). Error given by GetProps() is MAPI_W_ERRORS_RETURNED.

Comment: If the property does not exist in that particular MSG file, it is expected that you will receive an error. In your particular case, the PSPropValue array will contain a property of type PT_ERROR. SPropValue.Value.err will be MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND. Take a look at the MSG file with OutlookSpy (click OpenIMsgOnIStg button): http://www.dimastr.com/outspy